# Lookahead not matching unless there are brackets in the string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using this negative lookahead to search a single line string:

```
/\s+(?![^[]*]).+/g
```

This matches both of the following:

```
// String 1
a.casd-234[test='asfd asdf'] abc defg

// String 2
asf.one.two.three four five six
```

This returns `abc defg` and `four five six`

I tried writing an express to get the values before the text (`a.casd-234[test='asfd asdf']`, `asf.one.two.three`):

```
/.+(?<=[^[]*])\s/g
```

This works on string one, but on string two it doesn't work as it doesn't find anything since there is no `[` and `]` characters in the string.

What am I doing incorrectly with this lookbehind?

Comment: I am parsing selectors. I then convert it to an `HTMLElement`. The format is `selector textContent` where the first space that isn't between `[` and `]` separates the two.

Comment: Just use [the same `/\s+(?![^[]*]).+/` pattern with `.replace`](https://regex101.com/r/dTWteo/1) and replace with an empty string

Comment: if there is a comma after the `]` that is considered invalid format. Also, the `textContent` is optional...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Wow... such as simple solution that works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the regex to *match* a string from some point to its end (the `.+` at the end of the regex does that, matches 1+ chars other than line breaks, up to the line/string end).

Thus, the simplest solution is to use the same pattern with a `.replace` method:

```js
var rx = /\s+(?![^[]*]).+/;
console.log("a.casd-234[test='asfd asdf'] abc defg".replace(rx, ''));
console.log("asf.one.two.three four five six".replace(rx, ''));
```

Note you do not need `g` modifier here as you need to only replace once. If the string might have multiple lines, replace each `.` with `[^]` or `[\s\S]`.